# unexpected regex match

Tags: ruby, regex

Can anyone explain why the following test is not passing.  The regex is getting a match where I do not want one.

I want to find a match on text that begins with Tel, Fax or Web but for some reason, the url in the test is getting a match:

```
  def test_url_should_match
    assert_no_match(/^[tel|fax|web]/i, "www.jehall.co.uk")
  end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is my preg_match syntax valid?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246239/is-my-preg-match-syntax-valid)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it with

```
assert_no_match(/^(tel|fax|web)/i, "www.jehall.co.uk")
```

That should work. Otherwise you're matching against the characters, i.e. the w in web will match.

Answer (score 4):

`[...]` in a regular expression specifies a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), which tells the regular expression engine to match one of these characters contained within brackets. Therefore, `[tel|fax|web]` means "match t or e or l or | or f or a or x or w or e or b" (the fact that `|` appears more than once in the class is irrelevant). Since the string starts with a w -- which is in the character class -- the pattern matches.

As other answers have said, you want to use parentheses `(...)` to group your alternation instead.

Comment: Actually, the fact that `|` appears multiple times *is* relevant, since it will generate a warning, which, if the OP actually bothered to *read*, would already have told him what is wrong: `warning: character class has duplicated range: /[^[tel|fax|web]]/`

Comment: @Jörg it doesn't give me a warning in irb or on Rubular, but fair point.

Answer (score 2):

You should use

```
/^(?:tel|fax|web)/i
```

Comment: Why do you have the Elvis smiley `?:` there?

Comment: @Aillyn: So that it doesn't create a capture.

Comment: @Aillyn: Are you suggesting the `?:` should not be there?